# What is the name of this spell and which mastery give it?

Tags: titan-quest

One of Hades Generals have a spell that creates a large circle on the ground under the target it is attacking that sucks health and energy of the enemies within. Is there a mastery to give this spell and what is it's name?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds kind of like Death Nova in the spirit mastery, but that one can only be cast by the summoned Lich King.  It could be though that the NPCs can cast them without having to summon a Lich King.

Comment: I think the death nova create a circle around the character that casts it. The spell I mean creates a remote circle.It is directed to be around the target but as the target moves it stays in its place in the ground.

Comment: You are right, death nova is an aura around the character, it wasn't entirely clear that the circle was detached, sorry.